# iOS accessibility voiceover focus on tableview row shifts/scrolls it down a bit

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, accessibility, voiceover

I have a tableview with a few rows. If I enable voice over and focus on the first row, the whole tableview scrolls down a little bit. Is this an expected behaviour? If not, how do I fix it?